# GitHub deleted files are throwing off language stats

Tags: github, github-linguist

I deleted a bunch of .cc files on GitHub, but it stills sees them for the purpose of calculating language stats.  So it labels the repo as C++ even though it's all Python.

I read through guide here but didn't find anything about how it handles deleted files.
https://github.com/github/linguist#how-linguist-works-on-githubcom

Edit: The reason I thought this happened is that when I click the C++ percentage it shows all the .cc files in the folder where they used to be.  But I actually didn't delete them, I just moved them into a folder called `generated`.  After waiting overnight, now it shows the files in the correct location in the generated folder, so it was just a time delay issue.
But now I am not sure why they're still showing.  From the Linguist docs,  I thought anything inside a `generated` folder is ignored.

Comment: What's the URL of the repository? What makes you think they're still taken into account in language statistics?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `.gitattributes` file in the root directory of the repo with the following contents:

```
path/to/folder/with/c++/files/* linguist-vendored
```

You can add more lines to the file if you want to ignore multiple folders.

Comment: If they deleted the `.cc` files, the Linguist override you propose shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @pchaigno OP said they deleted "a bunch of files", not all files.

Comment: Yes. They also said `it's all Python`. So even if there are C++ files remaining, they probably don't know where these files are located. I'm just not sure an override is the right fix here; it might make the problem disappear, but it seems unlikely to fix the root cause.